# Getting 'cannot verify server identity' only on wireless LAN. Is this a MITM attack?

Tags: man-in-the-middle, wireless, iphone

I am getting the notification 'Cannot verify server identity' for every single website I try to open on an iPhone. This, however, only happens when connected to a certain WLAN.

On mobile internet this does not show up.

I already have reason to distrust this WLAN. Is this, however, credible evidence that a man-in-the-middle attack is taking place?

If so, what is the best way to collect evidence and maybe even proof of the MITM? Run wireshark on an interface connected to the WLAN?

Or are there any other plausible explanations for this?

Edit: This used to not happen on this WLAN before the owner became.. hostile in several different ways. They are IT savvy.

Comment: When you connect to this WLAN, and attempt to access popular sites like google.com, stackexchange.com, etc. what certificates are you seeing for these sites?  Are the certificates signed by a known/trusted CA?  If not, then that would explain what you are seeing, and this is an attempted MITM attack.

Comment: If you go to an insecure site like http://neverssl.com/ , does it load, or do you get redirected to a captive portal or something?

Comment: Hm, today the warnings disappeared and I'm getting the same certificates via mobile and WLAN.

Comment: It started again - this time I got the certificate: when I access google.com, it points to www.routerlogin.net at 192.168.1.2. I feel this is sketchy. This is a private WLAN in a private home. Afaik there is only one router here, and that should be at 192.168.1.1. Is there any non-suspicious reason for a routerlogin.net redirect just for my devices? (The children's devices are not getting this. All this is happening in an ugly divorce, btw. Spouse is a very.. troublesome person, working in IT.)